# Postgresql CASE statement schema error

Tags: postgresql, case

I'm getting a 3F000 error from the following CASE statement.

```
select 
entity.level1
,   sum(trans_clean.amount_calculated) as total_spend
,   sum(CASE WHEN extract(year from age(supplier.open_date::trans_clean.date_calculated)) <= 5 AND org_type = 'SMALL BUSINESS' THEN trans_clean.amount_calculated END) small_young
,   trans_clean.date_calculated
from
    entity, supplier, trans_clean
where   
    trans_clean.supplier_id = supplier.supplier_id and
    trans_clean.entity_id = entity.entity_id and
date_calculated > '2011-12-01'
group by
    entity.level1
,   total_spend
,   small_young
,   trans_clean.date_calculated
;
```

The error is as follows:

```
ERROR: schema "trans_clean" does not exist
SQL state: 3F000
```

The statement works without the CASE line, I'm running the query in PGAdmin III and the right schema (public) is definitely selected.

Comment: `::` is the cast operator in Postgres. Do you really created a data type named `date_calculated` in the schema `trans_clean`? What are you trying to do with the expression `supplier.open_date::trans_clean.date_calculated`?

Comment: I'm trying to define the age of a company at the time of a transaction. So, taking the age of a company `supplier.open` and getting the time passed at the time of the transaction `trans_clean.date_calculated`.